# Google Earth detected an error while trying to authenticate. error code: 1a

Tags: google-earth

When trying to start Google Earth today on Debian Buster got this:

[image]

I didn't know that any authenticating was involved with earth.  What gives?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why the above error suddenly appeared; perhaps this version is no longer supported.

**Fixed by:**

- Uninstalling what I think was my originally deb file used to install: `google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb`.  (`sudo apt-get purge google-earth-stable_current_amd64')
- Then installing the `google-earth-pro-stable` package from the Debian Buster repository.  (`sudo apt-get install google-earth-pro-stable')
- I then had to then manually get rid of my old xdg google-earth.desktop file.

---

(BTW, not sure what Debian's other package option (`google-earth-ec-stable`) is, but it might also work??)